# Core Data: How can I update a TableView field from an alert?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a TableView created using Core Data. The user can "add" a new record onto the TableView easily - however, I have written an update function that displays a update alert which allows the user to modify the recently added fields. Here is the "updateContact function:

```
 func updateBusinessContact(name: String, email: String, phone: String, company: String)
{
    // create an Alert with a textFields for all ContactBusiness fields
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Update Contact Business",
                                            message: "",
                                            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    // add the textField to the Alert. Create a closuer to handle the configuration
    alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.text = name
        textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardType.namePhonePad
        //            textField.secureTextEntry = true    // password entry
    })

    alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.text = email
        textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardType.emailAddress
    })

    alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.text = phone
        textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardType.phonePad
    })

    alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.placeholder="Street"
        textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardType.default
    })

    alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.placeholder="City"
        textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardType.default
    })

    alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.text = "oh"
        textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardType.default
    })

    alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.text = "44121"
        textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardType.numberPad
    })

    alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.text = company
        textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardType.default
    })

    // create a default action for the Alert
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(
        title: "Ok",
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,
        handler: {(alertAction: UIAlertAction!) in
            /// get the input from the alert controller
            let name: String = (alertController.textFields![0]).text!
            let email: String = (alertController.textFields![1]).text!
            let phone: String = (alertController.textFields![2]).text!
            let street: String = (alertController.textFields![3] ).text!
            let city: String = (alertController.textFields![4] ).text!
            let state: String = (alertController.textFields![5] ).text!
            let zip: String = (alertController.textFields![6] ).text!
            let company: String = (alertController.textFields![7]).text!

            // add Contact to the managedOBject
            _ = ContactBusiness(managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext,
                                name: name, email: email, phone: phone, street:street, city: city, state: state, zip: zip, company: company)


            // save the managedObject
            CoreDataHelper.addContactBusiness(managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)

            // get all Contacts from CoreData
            self.cbArray = CoreDataHelper.getAllContactBusiness(managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)

            // reload the data into the TableView
            self.tvContacts.reloadData()
    })

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(
        title: "Cancel",
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel,
        handler:nil)

    // add the action to the Alert
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    // display the Alert
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I believe the issue I am having is revolving somewhere around this block of code

```
  // add Contact to the managedOBject
            _ = ContactBusiness(managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext,
                                name: name, email: email, phone: phone, street:street, city: city, state: state, zip: zip, company: company)
```

This works, but it doesn't Update the pre existing TableView entry - it just adds another object with the updated info onto the Table.

How can I store the user modified fields in the ContactBusiness object?

(P.S this is for an assignment)

Thanks in advance, I can provide any other info required.

Comment: You need to pass the existing NSManagedObject Contact into this function and then simply update the properties of that object.

Comment: Do you have an example of this? I understand but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

On table view's didSelectMethod,
Here I hope your Core Data table's name is ContactBusiness if anything else that change Accordingly,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

         currentContactBusiness = self.cbArray[indexPath.row]
        //you can call function updateBusinessContact here
    }


//Updated Function
func updateBusinessContact(name: String, email: String, phone: String, company: String, currentContactBusiness : ContactBusiness)
{
     //update the details of currentContactBusiness
}
```

Note : This is just pseudo code, might contain syntax error